# Forçar as URLs com www. para sem o www. com htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria que ao digitar na URL http://www.meusite.com.br o .htaccess redirecionasse sempre para http://meusite.com.br, preciso deste 4 caracteres extras para as campanhas publicitarias.

O oposto com o .htaccess é desta forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meusite.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.meusite.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Este acima, redireciona de http://meusite.com/pages.html para http://www.meusite.com/pages.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta alterar a expressão regular e a URL de redirecionamento.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://meusite.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```